# Android device giving timeout error when making http request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am getting a timeout error on my request in my android app. I have set the retry policy but it did not solve the issue. When tested on my emulator it works fine with no error, but when using a real device to test it gives the timeout error.

```
public void makeRequest(final String user, final String cred)
    {
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/map/api/login";

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
                            String token = jsonResponse.getString("token");


                            if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
                            {
                                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout), jsonResponse.getString("message"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                            {
                                System.out.println(jsonResponse);
                                Intent loader = new Intent(home.this,webViewActivity.class);
                                loader.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,token);
                                startActivity(loader);
                            }

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("portal[username]", user);
                params.put("portal[password]", cred);
                params.put("portal[From]","web");
                return params;
            }
        };
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                7000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(postRequest);


    }
```

The error i get is below

```
08-18 12:42:46.341 16112-16112/com.mobile.map.map_mobile W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
08-18 12:42:46.341 16112-16112/com.mobile.map.map_mobile W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:141)
08-18 12:42:46.341 16112-16112/com.mobile.map.map_mobile W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Comment: Try your API first in Postman Client, if it does not give some error there then let us know.

Comment: I did check the API url, it seems the error is in your server side.

Comment: @Enzokie i checked it on postman and it seems it was the API.

Comment: Changing the API to http://192.168.43.34:8888/map/api/login which works on Postman is still giving me a similar error on my android device

Comment: 1. Override  `getHeader()` instead of `getParams()` 2. Change param `portal[username]` to `username` only and so on. 3. Remove your retry policy code. Let Me know if that works

Comment: The reason i have to use the portal[username] is because that's how the developer at the backend designed the api for some reason.

Comment: it works when i connect to the version of the webpage that is hosted online though

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on the different device and on the different network. If it doesn't work please check the response time in postman if it is more than 2500 millisecond(volley default timeout), increase the volley's default timeout in DefaultRetryPolicy.class

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your Key value pair is for Body.

```
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

            try {
                params.put("portal[username]", user);
                params.put("portal[password]", cred);
                params.put("portal[From]","web");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
               // Do something
            }

        Response.Listener<JSONObject> jsonObjectListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // Response here
                }
            };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new  Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Error here
                }
            };

       String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/map/api/login";

       JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params,
                    jsonObjectListener, errorListener);

       Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(jsonRequest);
```